# Javascript array.map() returning array of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm having a strange issue with mapping an array to a new object type in javascript. I have a getter function like this:

```
get azOptions() {
    return this.arr?.map(az => {
        test:"asdf";
    });
}
```

...

```
console.log(this.azOptions);
```

The array contains 2 elements when I call the getter, but it maps to an array of 2 undefined elements as can be seen in this browser output:

[image]

Comment: Your map function isn't returning an object, it's a [_label_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and a string literal.

Comment: what result did you expect?

Comment: That's because you are not returning anything from `array#map`.  Wrap your object with `()` to return an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do following:

```
get azOptions() {
   return this.arr?.map((az) => ({
     test: "asdf",
   }));
}
```

Your problem is, that you currently don't return an Object .

Comment: thanks, that worked. I thought the object after az=> would already be the value returned.